# W10 won't set word as default application for .doc documents

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, file-association

On a computer running w10 with office 365 suddenly the file association of office was lost, I have fixed it except for the .doc files, if I double click a file it will open Word but a message will show up saying that Word isn't the default application for those kind of files

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling office with no success. Also the file association in the control panel is correctly showing Word  as the default program for doc files

Any ideas on what can be happening?

Regards

Comment: Try setting another app as default, then word again.

Comment: Open With, hit the checkbox, always use this program

Comment: I have setup notepad as the default application, then change it back to word, still no success, i also tried using open with

Answer (score -1):

I ran into a very similar problem except, in my case, the .doc files were set to Word 2007 rather than giving me the error message you got. My solution was to uninstall the old version of Office & then run a repair install on 365. Everything is now working as expected.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem, and the fix for me was to right click and select "open with another app". Word wasn't listed so I had to select "more apps". Then when I found Word there was a little checkbox titled "make this the default app for opening .doc"(or something like that). This seems to have fixed it for me.

Comment: OP already stated this didn't work for him.